# More elegent way to store and get the values from a dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have some students, and I created several `dict`s to store their information. Each `dict` has the same keys with different values. The code is as follows.

```
dict_score = {
'Mike': 100,
'John':98,
'HuxiaoMing':78,
'Mechele':66}

dict_sex = {
'Mike': "male",
'John':"male",
'HuxiaoMing':"female",
'Mechele':"male"}

dict_height = {
'Mike': 170,
'John':198,
'HuxiaoMing':178,
'Mechele':166}

def get_degree(score):
  if score>90:
    return "good"
  elif score<60:
    return "bad"
  else:
    return "normal"


dict_degree = {
'Mike': get_degree(dict_score['Mike']),
'John':get_degree(dict_score['John']),
'HuxiaoMing':get_degree(dict_score['HuxiaoMing']),
'Mechele':get_degree(dict_score['Mechele'])}

......
```

There are a couple of things which annoy me:

1. If I want to add new student, I need to change every `dict`. Sometimes I will forget some `dict`s.
2. If I want to include some new features for each student (like there age, or favorite books). I need to create a new `dict` and type their name again.

Is there any more elegant way to store this information and use it?  I hope it could be as easy as I did in Excel.

Comment: why not have a dict per student, not per property? This just looks like sub-optimal design. Also it may be more convenient to have different container or even have custom class

Comment: I agree, that is a funny way to essentially do data handling.

Comment: @buran then I will still need to write all properties' names for each student. Now the number of properties is greater than the number of students. I hope to write all 'student name' and all 'property name' only once like we do in Excel.

Comment: Why don't you just put this information in a tabular data type like a DataFrame?

Comment: @BatWannaBe Because some times the property is not just a 'string' or 'int number', sometimes the property is a custom class or a function, which can not be stored at DataFrame.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "like we do in Excel". If you write VBA code it will do more or less the same.

Comment: It looks like you are leaning more or less toward custom class in my opinion

Comment: @JingnanJia pandas.DataFrame can hold a dtype of `object`, which will contain a reference to any Python object including functions and instances of custom classes.

Comment: I suggest you create a `Student` **`class`** that can contain any/all the properties you wish. You can define methods in it to do things to set, update, delete it's attributes.

Comment: I had an answer with a `Student` `class` but thinking all again, it did not make any sense to have it *if there is no other need than hold data*.  The situation is different if one wants for example give a student as a parameter to a function. Having `StudentContainer` instead of plain `pd.DataFrame` gives the needed flexibility of calculating new columns, adding students, loading & saving data.

Comment: Of course part of the specifications was here in the comments section. Oh well, for OOP approach, see the edit history in my answer.  Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you to use Pandas for this. You can use pandas dataframes to manage data like this with ultimate flexibilty:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dict_score = {
'Mike': 100,
'John':98,
'HuxiaoMing':78,
'Mechele':66}

dict_sex = {
'Mike': "male",
'John':"male",
'HuxiaoMing':"female",
'Mechele':"male"}

dict_height = {
'Mike': 170,
'John':198,
'HuxiaoMing':178,
'Mechele':166}

df = pd.DataFrame({'Score': dict_score,'Sex': dict_sex, 'Height': dict_height}).reset_index()
```

Here our dataframe (`df`) will look like:

```
        index  Score     Sex  Height
0        Mike    100    male     170
1        John     98    male     198
2  HuxiaoMing     78  female     178
3     Mechele     66    male     166
```

Now you can easily apply the `get_score` function and create new column like this:

```
df['Degree'] = df['Score'].apply(get_degree)
```

Here now our df will look like:

```
        index  Score     Sex  Height  Degree
0        Mike    100    male     170    good
1        John     98    male     198    good
2  HuxiaoMing     78  female     178  normal
3     Mechele     66    male     166  normal
```

Let's work more!

To get any column (Each columns are pandas series) use like:

```
df['COLUMN_NAME']
```

Now like we want to get average of the scores of the students:

```
df['Score'].average()
```

Get descriptive statistics:

```
df['Score'].describe()
```

And using `.apply()` you can apply your own functions with powerful combinations of `lambda`.

Comment: Nicely explained answer.

Answer (score 1):

### Workflow: csv -> python -> csv

Below I show you a workflow **csv -> python -> csv**, which I think would be most convenient. You would load the input data from `input.csv` and then save the output data as `out.csv`. This way you can create your input data in *e.g.* Excel and read the output in Excel, too. The heavy-lifting & any calculations are done in python.

The API would look like this:

```
sc = StudentContainer("input.csv")
sc.add_student(name="Laura", sex="female", height=155, score=92) # Could also add rows programmatically, if wanted
sc.df.to_csv("out.csv", index=False)
```

The `input.csv` would look like this: (edited in Excel)

```
name,score,sex,height
Mike,100,male,170
John,98,male,198
HuxiaoMing,78,female,178
Mechele,66,male,166
```

and `out.csv` like this: (opened in Excel, if wanted)

```
name,score,sex,height,degree
Mike,100,male,170,good
John,98,male,198,good
HuxiaoMing,78,female,178,normal
Mechele,66,male,166,normal
Laura,92,female,155,good
```

### Code

```py
import pandas as pd


def degree(score):
    if score > 90:
        return "good"
    elif score < 60:
        return "bad"
    else:
        return "normal"


class StudentContainer:
    def __init__(self, file=None):

        self.df = pd.DataFrame() if file is None else self.from_csv(file)

    def add_student(self, **data):

        # calculate new columns before adding to self.df
        data["degree"] = degree(data["score"])
        self.df = self.df.append(data, ignore_index=True)

    def from_csv(self, file):

        df = pd.read_csv(file)
        df["degree"] = df["score"].apply(degree)
        return df
```

#### StudentContainer

- Class for managing a group of students that belong together. You could have different groups.
- Attribute `cs.df` for holding a [pandas.DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html). An `.csv` or `.xlsx` file can be easily made from output with [`sc.df.to_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) or [`sc.df.to_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)
- You could extend this to also have other convenience methods. As an example, there is `sc.from_csv()` to get the data from csv file.

Answer (score 1):

Write a function (once) to operate on all the dictionaries everytime you need to add a student.

```
def f(name,sex=None,height=None,score=None):
    dict_score[name] = score
    dict_sex[name] = sex
    dict_height[name] = height
    dict_degree[name] = get_degree(dict_score[name])}
```

Make sure you define the function in the same scope as the dictionaries so it *can see them*.

Answer (score 0):

So I think the comments have gotten at the key issue here, which is that you've oriented your data in such a way that doing what you want (adding a new student) is harder than it would be if the data were oriented differently.

If there's some reason you need to load data in the way you've done, but then subsequently work with names, here's a handy bit of code for you:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_score, orient='index', columns=["score"]),
           pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_sex, orient='index', columns=["sex"]),
           pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_height, orient='index', columns=["height"])],axis=1).T.to_dict()
```

This provides a transformation that you may find useful when adding additional data, and/or moving back and forth:

```
{'Mike': {'score': 100, 'sex': 'male', 'height': 170},
 'John': {'score': 98, 'sex': 'male', 'height': 198},
 'HuxiaoMing': {'score': 78, 'sex': 'female', 'height': 178},
 'Mechele': {'score': 66, 'sex': 'male', 'height': 166}}
```

You can move back and forth, like this:

[image]